# Personal Protective Equipment Database Structure

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, database-design

I have been asked by my manager to design a Personal Protective Equipment Database for the procurement dept,using SQL Server.In gathering my requirements for the database,I came up with 5 PPE categories:Hands,Eyes & Faces,Head,Body,Footwear.

Currently have one table which stores all the aforementioned categories,

**PPCatTable:*
Hands,
Eyes & Faces,
Head,
Body,
Footwear**

For each category,there are several has subsets i.e  for

**Footwear:*
Level of resistance to electric,
HasSteelToe,
Color,
Height**,

**Gloves:*
Hazard,
Degereeof hazard,
ProtectiveMaterial**

but  I'm stumped on what the structure of the children's table should be look like,how to store the different subsets for each category.Each subset has different  number attributes and procurement dept insists on capturing all the different attributes.

Should  I create a table for each child category?

What field should be referenced the child's primary key for the  PPEEOrderDetails table?

Should I store the corresponding child attributes as an XML data type in the parent category table?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the entity **supertype / subtype** technique to model your items.  Consider the following data model:

[image: ERD]

Your various categories each have their own table, because they have distinct attribute sets.  Each sub-category has as its primary key, a column which is also a foreign key to the supertype table: `PPEQUIP`.

Note that `PPEQUIP` is *not* a list of categories, like your `PPCatTable`.  `PPEQUIP` contains a record for every single item in each of the subtype tables.  The columns in `PPEQUIP` will be the common identifier and a `partitioning attribute` which is a colum that indicates which subtype applies to the item.  If there are other attributes that all types have in common, then those common attributes would also go in `PPEQUIP`.

Now when you have a table that needs to reference equipment in general, without specific regard to what category the equipment falls into, such as your `ORDER_DETAIL` then that foreign key reference goes to the supertype table (i.e. `PPEQUIP`).  If on the other hand, you need to reference only a specific category, then you would do that at the subtype level.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I'm still a bit hazy on the structure of the PPEQUIP table.If a record in PPE_FEET(Levelofresistancetoelectric, HasSteelToe, Color, Height) is(20,yes(1),red(4),10) and in PPE_Hands(Hazard, Degereeof hazard,ProtectiveMaterial) is(1,2,5,9).How would they be represented in PPEQUIP?Could you give an example of the PPEQUIP?

Comment: @user1013666 - PPEQUIP has only the columns that are common to every kind of equipment.  If this is just the common surrogate key (IDENTITY) plus the partitioning attribute (PartTypeCode) then that is OK.  There may be others too, however.  Maybe you have an internal equipment ID code or something else you track for everything, such as "date added" or "minimum order quantity" or what have you.